# Books on Zeta Regularization Product

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Does anybody know some book on zeta regularization, and the zeta regularization product? I'm quite interested on the topic but I would need a book with some review...

Comment: Since products can be reduced to sums in multiple ways, i'd say you should focus on "normal" regularization. Most likely the product will be a sub-topic in the book itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are books in merit. But surely you will find lots of notes on the internet. Just try to Google those:

- Zeta function regularization filetype:pdf
- Riemann Zeta Regularization filetype:pdf
- Riemann zeta function Hawking filetype:pdf
- Zeta function methods filetype:pdf
- Zeta function quantum field theory filetype:pdf

Comment: Yes I indeed would like to know if there's something more systematic from the mathematical point of view